# Does kafka group works independent of kafka topic?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have a situation as - I have two java application(lets say a1 and a2) running with same kafka consumer group(lets say g1) and on different topics(lets say t1 and t2) and have only 1 partition(lets say p1). a1 consume messages from t1 and produces to t2. a2 consume messages from t2 and do some processing. In such situation, Could a1 hold or create blockage for a2 so that a1 remains idle and not doing anything or not consuming any messages? I am getting messages consumed by a2 when using different group but with same group g1, no luck at all.

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to do. But you could not start java applications with same kafka consumer group. consumer group is attribute of consumer

Comment: @gstackoverflow I didn't get your point that we couldn't start java applications with same kafka consumer group. Isn't is possible to start two diff java applications that has kafka with same consumer group?

I am using kafka within java applications (springboot framework) and I have two different applications that are using the same consumer group which is set by using group.id=mygrp kafka consumer props. Please correct me know if I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: you are correct.  If you use same consumer group for both consumer applications  - they(in total) will get all messages

Comment: I don't understand what do you want. a1 consumer consume messages from t1. a2 consumer consume messages from t2. It doesn't related with consumer groups. Behaviour should not be changed if a1 and a2 in same partition group or not